# Coffeescript class syntax different in node?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, frappe

I've been using coffeescript on the front end for a few years now. And am familiar with class syntax looking something like this:

```
  class MyClass
      methodOne : ->
         console.log "methodOne Called"
      methodTwo : (arg, arrg) ->
         console.log "methodTwo Called"
```

Recently I've been playing with node and the [frappe](https://github.com/dweldon/frappe) boilerplate for web applications with coffeescript and node.

This script using CoffeeScript classes for routes with the following syntax:

```
  class MyClass
      @methodOne = ->
         console.log "methodOne Called"
      @methodTwo = (arg, arrg) ->
         console.log "methodTwo Called"
```

The only usage difference I can note from my normal usage, is that the Routes.coffee file consumes the class directly rather than making a `new` object. So:

```
   MyClass.methodOne()

   # vs

   new MyClass().methodOne()
```

Now I've learned that the `@methodOne` syntax is not using `.prototype` while the other syntax does. But why would this make the usage fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, methods that begin with `@` are class methods where everything else is an instance methods.  With instances methods, `:` essentially means public where `=` means private.  The "public" vs "private" dichotomy doesn't exist with class methods in CoffeeScript, so `:` and `=` do the ame thing.  They are both public.

For example, take a look at this class:

```
class MyClass
  @methodOne = -> 
  @methodTwo : -> 
  methodThree : ->
  methodFour = ->
```

That evaluates to the following JavaScript:

```
var MyClass;

MyClass = (function() {
  var methodFour;

  function MyClass() {}

  MyClass.methodOne = function() {};
  MyClass.methodTwo = function() {};
  MyClass.prototype.methodThree = function() {};
  methodFour = function() {};

  return MyClass;

})();
```

So, `methodOne` and `methodTwo` are both public class methods, `methodThree` gets to go on the prototype, so it is a public instance method and `methodFour` becomes a variable within the class that can be used internally but never gets exposed publically.

Hope that answers what you are asking?